# Model automatically tracking even when real object is not available using Microsoft Hololens 2

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia, hololens, mrtk

During the development of a HoloLens 2 application involving the tracking of multiple objects and QR codes, an issue arose where the model tracking occasionally indicated that an object was being tracked even when it was not within the user's field of view.

I have attempted to utilize both Advanced model tracking and model tracking, as well as guide view and 360 tracking. Additionally, I have experimented with altering the camera device mode

Answer (score 1):

> Device Tracking maintains tracking even when a target is no longer in
> view. It's automatically enabled for all targets when the Positional
> Device Tracker is enabled. For HoloLens applications, the Positional
> Device Tracker is started automatically in Unity.
>
> Vuforia Engine automatically fuses the poses from camera tracking and
> HoloLens's spatial tracking to provide stable target poses independent
> of whether the target is seen by the camera or not.

For a more detailed explanation of the process, please refer to [Using Vuforia with Unity - Mixed Reality | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/vuforia-development-overview#device-tracking-with-vuforia). To enable/disable the Device Tracker in Unity and make configurations, please visit https://developer.vuforia.com/library/device-tracking/enable-device-tracking-unity.

Comment: Note that on Hololens it is not possible to get tracking working with the device tracker disabled however it might be possible to use the target StatusInfo to differentiate an actively tracked target from a target out of view https://developer.vuforia.com/library/device-tracking/enable-device-tracking-unity#use-the-tracking-status-to-enable-extended-tracking-for-individu